# Laravel 5.1 ошибка при Composer Update

Tags: laravel, composer

Поставил какой-то пакет - выкинуло ошибку. Когда удалил, всё осталось также:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Invalid filename provided.
>   Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
>   [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output:

Причем подобная ошибка пропадает, если поставить `debug` в `true`. Само приложение работает нормально, но эта вещь раздражает. Куда "копать"?

Comment: поделитесь с нами какой пакет вы ставили, покажите composer.json, app/config.php, еще может какие-то файлы меняли.

Answer (score 2):

Перейди в папку с сайтом:
cd path_site

Выполни:
php artisan optimize

Скорее всего при подключении пакета, ты просто добавил сервис провайдер и т.п. :) вот и ругается

Comment: при php artisan optimize ругается [RuntimeException]          
Invalid filename provided.

Comment: а лог пустой при этом?